# How to solve the Issue when VB.Net application connect to the online MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
Dim myConnectionString As String

myConnectionString = "server=xxx.yyy.zzz.aaaa:3306;" _
            & "uid=aaa;" _
            & "pwd=bbb;" _
            & "database=ccc"

Try
    conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString
    conn.Open()

Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
conn.Close()
```

Server was Ubuntu 18.04

Here is error screenshot.
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHFiw.png)

Anyone have solved this issue before?
Thanks for your support.

Comment: Everything looks fantastic to me. And, unless you tell us the error message no one will be able to help you

Comment: You need to specify the port as a separate parameter; see [MySQL connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) for examples. It is a good idea to use the [MySqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.htm) class to build the connection string: it will take care of any character escapes and so on for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a fan of constructing connections strings - whether using the dedicated builder or not - from defined connection parameters:

```
Dim (or Const) Server As String = "MyServer"
Dim (or Const) Port As UInteger= 3456
Dim (or Const) Database As String = "MyDatabase"
Dim (or Const) UserId As String = "MyUser"
Dim (or Const) Password As String = "MyPassword"

Dim mySql As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder() With {
    .Server = Server,
    .Port = Port,
    .Database = Database,
    .UserId = UserId,
    .Password = Password
}
```

Result from MySQL String Builder (`mySql.ConnectionString`):

```
server=MyServer;port=3456;database=MyDatabase;user id=MyUser;password=MyPassword
```

Or roll your own:

```
Dim myConn As String = $"Server={Server};Port={Port};Database={Database};Uid={UserId};Pwd={Password}"
```

(Note alternate parameter naming for *UserId* and *Password*.)

A useful resource is the Connection Strings website: https://connectionstrings.com.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong in my code.
Should specify the port as a separate parameter as Andrew Morton answered.

Here is new connection string which connect with the remote sql server.

```
myConnectionString = "server=xxx.yyy.zzz.ddd;" _
                    & "port=aaaa;" _
                    & "uid=bbbb;" _
                    & "pwd=xxxxxx;" _
                    & "database=eeeee"
```